# Permission issue with Invoke-PnPQuery

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp

I am trying to run the code below to update the "noCrawl" property but I am facing an issue with Invoke-PnPQuery:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Credentials $cred
$Web = Get-PnPWeb
$Web.NoCrawl = $true
$Web.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

I get the following error

> Invoke-PnPQuery : Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource. Au caractère Ligne:2 : 13 Invoke-PnPQuery CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-PnPQuery], ServerUnauthorizedAccessException FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.InvokeQuery

Seems like a permissions issue, but i'm struggling with it.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Your code worked for me, so you definitely have some permission issue. Can you manually set it by going to Site Settings-> Search and offline availability -> and set "No" for Allow this site to appear in search results

Comment: Try switching to another site collection administrator account and run the command again. Run the upgrade command “Update-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell*” if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out.

To perform an action like to upadate "nocrawl" property, you need to have another property of the web "-DenyAndAddCustomizePages" switched to false:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $adminURL -Credentials $cred
Set-PnPSite -Identity $url -DenyAndAddCustomizePages $false
```

Then the code can be executed without any problem